# observables as functions or variables. angular 4 typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I have an observable as a function in a service.

```
getlistofcities(){
    return this.httpclient.get(getcitylist);
```

i inject it into a component.

```
this.landingpagedependancyservice.getlistofcities()
      .subscribe(
        (city:any) =>{
          this.cities = city;
        }
      );
```

but I noticed when I go to my ngOnDestroy()

and I try to subscribe I get the error

```
 Property 'unsubscribe' does not exist on type 'Observable<Object>'
```

which makes me think I am doing something wrong by placing the observable inside a function. Should I put it as a variable?

Comment: You're asking a question about code, but you don't post that code. All we can say is what the error message already says: you're trying to call unsuscribe() on an observable, instead of calling it on a Subscription. Subscription is what is returned by subscribe().

Comment: so then it should be noted as a variable. sweet. You answered my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a variable to store the return value of `subscribe`, such as:

```
let subscription = this.landingpagedependancyservice.getlistofcities()
      .subscribe(
        (city:any) =>{
          this.cities = city;
        }
      );
```

then In your `ngOnDestory`, use

```
subscription.unsubscribe()
```

to destroy the subscription.

Comment: and you win everything. Whats your address so I can send everything to your house?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to it in a more flexible and reusable way you should create a new Subject/Observable and use it in the takeUntil operator

```
private destroy$: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>(); 

this.landingpagedependancyservice.getlistofcities()
.takeUntil(destroy$)
  .subscribe(
    (city:any) =>{
      this.cities = city;
    }
  );
```

And then on the NgDestroy you should do the following:

```
destroy$.next(true);
destroy$.complete();
```

The type boolean is not mandatory it’s just an example of a possible case.

Answer (score 0):

so here is what I did.

from the LandingpageDependancyService:

```
 getlistofcities(){
        return this.httpclient.get(getcitylist);
      }

    then in the landingpagecomponent:

// subscription for city dependancy
 citylist : any;



 ngOnInit() {
     // get list of cities for city select
     this.citylist = this.landingpagedependancyservice.getlistofcities()
       .subscribe(
        (city:any) =>{
          this.cities = city;
        }
      );
  }

ngOnDestroy(){
// unsubscribe from city list
this.citylist.unsubscribe();
```

}